# How can we implement single sign on using Graph API in Angular using MSAL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

We make a project in which we implement Graph API and perform different actions on it now all things are going well but we just want to implement single sign on using Graph API in Angular so that we can authenticate the user for just first time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MSAL for authentication.
Graph API only providers user info etc., it doesn't handle authentication.
For Angular, you can use [@azure/msal-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular).

Comment: yes we are using  @azure/msal-angular for authentication but user have to enter their credential every time when he comes to use our application which is we don't want. we want that if user authenticate one time then next time he don't have to enter their credential we can do it by using single sing on which i already ask that how can we implement it in our project?

Comment: Authorization Code flow with PKCE uses a refresh token that expires in 24 hours for front-end applications. So a daily login redirect/popup is necessary. However, the user would not necessarily need to enter their username and password again. If the user chooses "Keep me signed in", then it shouldn't ask them for their password the next day. There could also be organizational policies that require them to re-authenticate? Make sure you don't specify something like "prompt=login" in the authentication request too, as that would force the login screen to be shown.

Comment: yes you are right but we want to implement single sign on of Microsoft. by implementing this we can login just for once not again and again